# What is the best way to change data structures stored in firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to change one of the attributes `contact` of my JSON Store object to `phonenumber`. Here are my Store objects as seen from Firebase dashboard

[image]

I want to change `contact:` to `phonenumber:` for all of my Store objects all at once

[image]

My plan right now is to export the JSON and manually change them but there must be a better way that I do not know about. How do I do this most efficiently?

Also, How do I add another attribute to all of my Store objects at once as well, such as a `manager` attribute for all of the Store object.

Comment: Since the change to your data structure is entirely proprietary in each case, there isn't a tool to do this for you. Just write [a few lines of JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6099042) using once('value') and snapshot.forEach().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code Kato included in his comment, here's some JavaScript that will do it:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/path-to-your-node");
ref.on("child_added", function(snap) {
  var data = snap.val();
  data.phonenumber = data.contact;
  delete data.contact;
  ref.child(snap.name()).set(data, function(error) {
    if( error && typeof(console) !== 'undefined' && console.error ) {  console.error(error); }
  });
});
```

All you need to do is update the firebase hostname, and the path to the node that contains your list of users.

I tested it in on a browser console, but it should work in node.js too, if you want to run it as a command line script.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script in your favourite language (as long as it supports the Firebase API, though you could use the REST API too). In the script you can iterate through the data to modify and save the data.